# In RMarkdown how to source css file in a chunk?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I need to know how to source a CSS file to be applied to my .Rmd report, using a chunk in RMarkdown? Is it possible?

Actually, I would like to make `.css` file become a parameter.

Something like this below:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
source('style.css')

```
````

Comment: I think `source()` works only with rscripts. A chunck with css should be used with actual css code within. To include a css file in you Rmarkdown take a look [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html)

Comment: @JohanRosa thanks for your time! I was thinking about a css file becomes a parameter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `htmltools::includeCSS()`:

Contents of `my_css.css`:

```
p {
  color: red;
}
```

Contents of Rmd:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
params:
  my_css: my_css.css
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
htmltools::includeCSS(params$my_css)
```

Hello World!
````

Produces red text:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a css chunk with the `code` [chunk option](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#code-chunk) (which is intended to allow for programmatically inserted code)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
params:
  my_css: my_css.css
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```  

```{css, code = readLines(params$my_css)}

```

Hello World!
````